# JS how to access variable outside it's function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

Here is my code:

```
var pickupdate;
$(function(){
  $.datepicker.setDefaults(
    $.extend( $.datepicker.regional[ '' ] )
  );
  $( '#pickupdate' ).datepicker( {
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    maxDate: "+3m",
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function() { 
      pickupdate = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' ); 
      alert(pickupdate)
 }
  });
});
console.log(pickupdate)
```

The `alert` (within function) works while the `console.log` (outside function) shows `pickupdate` as `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try setting it within `$(function(){ var pickupdate;`

Comment: It's not possible. Any code that needs a value (`'getDate'`) from an event (`onSelect`) has to also be bound to or called by that event (like the `alert()` is).

Comment: You may set the variable outside all functions and edit it within the scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
$(function(){
    //Code here
});
```

You're basically binding that function to jQuery's document ready function, which is called after `console.log(pickupdate)` executes. The reason why it says `pickupdate` is undefined is because the `onSelect` function for the datepicker has not fired yet.

You could try encasing it in a function:

```
function LogValue() {
    console.log(pickupdate);
}
```

Then you could add that function as a click event to a button, and you'll see that when you change the datepicker value and click the button, it will log the correct value. [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/744g0kqx/)